# how to dynamically extend diff parent class?

Tags: java

Now there is a super BaseService, and it has two children classes: CompanyService, PersonService

```
BaseService (Abstract):
    - CompanyService
    - PersonService
```

Now there is a new situation, above design cannot fit, So I want to add a new subclass to  implement the specific logic,

```
BaseService(Abstract)
    - CompanyService
        - SpecificCompanyService 
    - PersonService
        - SpecificPersonService
```

but `SpecificCompanyService` and `SpecificPersonService` logic is same, do not need duplicate. So want to extract a super class again

```
CompanyService / PersonService:
    - BaseSpecificService (Abstract):
        - SpecificCompanyService / SpecificPersonService
```

but how to dynamically extend diff parent class? e.g. BaseSpecificService could extend CompanyService or PersonService dynamically.

```
SpecificCompanyService extends BaseSpecificService extends CompanyService
SpecificPersonService extends BaseSpecificService extends PersonService
```

Now My solution is just add a `SpecificUtils` and put the common logic into SpecificUtils. In this case, method in utils need more parameters, but if common login in abstract parent class, it will much simple.

PS.

Background: At first there is only a scheduler task situation, e.g. every 10 mins synchronizes changed companies, persons from Oracle to ElasticSearch, but now I want to support this situation, that is only synchronized the specific time range data from Oracle to ES.

Comment: *but SpecificCompanyService and SpecificPersonService logic is same,* - why not have this logic in the `BaseService` ?

Comment: Do you mean the logic in `SpecificCompanyService` is the same as its parent class or the same as `SpecificPersonService`? Do you want to use generics, i.e. `CompanyService<CompanyA>`? Have you considered passing the Company/Person logic in using dependency injection? The logic stays in `BaseSpecificService` but you pass the specifics in using another class/interface. But perhaps I don't understand what you actually want. Some concrete code/examples may help make the situation more tangible?

Answer (score 0):

If "SpecificCompanyService and SpecificPersonService logic is same" -> why don't create 
interface for this like SpecificService

My suggestion is

```
class SpecificCompanyService extends BaseService, implements SpecificService
class PersonService extends BaseService, implements SpecificService
```

Comment: The two lines look identical to me? What are your trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

As you said both **SpecificCompanyService** and **SpecificPersonService** have same logic for all of the above classes.

Hence you can make an ***abstract*** class **SpecificService** for both of the above(**SpecificCompanyService** and **SpecificPersonService**)

and after this your class hierarchy will be like this:

```
class CompanyService extends SpecificService
class PersonService extends SpecificService
class SpecificService implements BaseService
```